# How to get a whole day using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here is the Part of the code of DateTime Picker.When Someone Select StartDate & EndDate from date time picker it comes to unitHolidays.

In here i need get full holiday.I need to consider if someone select any Start Date but time is 12:00:00 AM to any End Date with time is 12:00:00 AM  ( ex : see full holiday )

Full Holiday
9/19/2013 12:00:00 AM  to 9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM

But my following code, it takes any 12 hour slot is a holiday.

```
  foreach (UnitHolidays uh in unitHolidays)
  {

       for (DateTime dth = uh.StartDate; dth <= uh.EndDate; dth = dth.AddDays(1))
       { 
           RadCalendarDay rcdHoliday = new RadCalendarDay();
           rcdHoliday.Date = dth.Date;
           rcdHoliday.IsDisabled = true;
           rcdHoliday.IsSelectable = true;
           rcdHoliday.ToolTip = "Holiday";
           rcdHoliday.ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumOrchid;
           rdpStDt.Calendar.SpecialDays.Add(rcdHoliday);
       }
   }
```

I need if someone select 12:00:00 AM to 12:00:00 AM then only I need to take it as a holiday.

Comment: What? Please, remove word 'holiday' from question and describe which problem you have.

Comment: This is a datetime picker code.When someone  select a anyday with time like 12:00:00 AM to next day 12:00:00 AM then it takes as a holiday.

Comment: @Alex, that still doesn't explain the problem though. This code doesn't seem related at all to what the **user selects.**

Answer (score 2):

As described, something like:

```
public class Holiday
{
     public DateTime Start { get; set; }
     public DateTime End { get; set; }

     public List<Holiday> GetHolidays()
     {
          return new List<Holiday>() { new Holiday() { 
                Start = new DateTime(2013, 9, 19), 
                End = new DateTime(2013, 9, 20)
          };
     }

     public bool IsHoliday(DateTime date)
     {
          return GetHolidays().Where(c => c.Start <= date && c.End >= date).Count() > 0;
     }
}
```

However, I think this would be a bit lighter and easier:

```
public class Holiday
{
     public List<DateTime> GetHolidays()
     {
          return new List<DateTime>() { 
               new DateTime(2013, 9, 19)
          };
     }

     public bool IsHoliday(DateTime date)
     {
          return GetHolidays().Where(c => c.Date == date.Date).Count() > 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 The second approach is the best one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a full day be described as `9/19/2013 12:00:00 AM` to `9/19/2013 11:59:59 PM` or anything `>=` to the start date and `<` the end date? You should use `<` and not `<=` as it will include the next day which isn't the same day.

You want something like this:

```
private bool IsHoliday(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return DateTime.Now >= startDate && DateTime.Now < endDate;
}
```

Comment: No my full day is 9/19/2013 12:00:00 AM to 9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Technically that would be 24 hours, but as soon as 9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM occurs, it will no longer be 9/19/2013. That is why I used the exclusive `<` operator and not the inclusive `<=` operator.

Comment: This could prove to be problematic as it causes the beginning and ending point to both be the date being checked as well as the previous and next day, respectively. (The full day requirement, not the code). Meaning if we had two lists: Holidays and NotHolidays and 9/19 is in holiday whereas 9/20 is in NotHolidays. That would mean that 9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM would return true for both IsHoliday and IsNotHoliday.

Comment: I realize now that using your List approach is more along the lines of the original requirements. I didn't fully understand what Alex wanted. My code simply checks a date range.